# Определение контуров лица в openCV

Tags: opencv

Доброго дня! Есть задача: определение контуров лица по фотографии и простановка ключевых точек. Есть облачные сервисы типа facemark, faceplusplus и многие другие, но практически никто из них не определяет точки в профиль, а те что определяют, делают это некачественно. Кроме того, для моей задачи желательно обращение непосредственно к программе на рабочей машине, чем работа через сервисы. Может работал кто-то с подобными вещами, может подсказать какие-то наработки?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что тут не сервис поиска работников